# Publish photo with "Send Message" call to action on Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, api, post, publish, messenger

I've been trying to do this for an entire week and is driving me nuts.

I've an app for restaurants that works through Facebook Messenger bot and to help restaurant owners I'm trying to schedule posts automatically through my web app with a "Send Message" button.

In short, **I want to create a post with a custom image uploaded from my site, with a "Send Message" button**.

This is easy if the restaurant owner just posts it manually on Facebook, he just selects clicks on publish, selects the "send message" option and uploads a photo, but it's not so easy doing it from the API.

Their documentation is pretty confusing and this is what I've tried so far.

On their `/{page-id}/feed` endpoint I send this:

```
{
  "call_to_action": {
    "type": "MESSAGE_PAGE",
    "value": {
      "link": "link-page"
    }
  },
  "message": "message"
}
```

This one works, it creates the post and shows the "Send Message" button.
But Facebook scraps the OG meta of the link given on the call_to_action parameter and shows the title, description and image of the link (which is required for call_to_action to work).

Then I tried to use the picture parameter, but when you give a picture, you have to config the link, title and description.

```
{
  "call_to_action": {
    "type": "MESSAGE_PAGE",
    "value": {
      "link": "link-page"
    }
  },
  "message": "message",
  "link": "link",
  "picture": "img-url",
  "title": "title",
  "description": "description"
}
```

This one would be perfect, but Facebook tells me that I must own the domain used on the links parameters, so I proceed to verify my domains on my business manager account to be open and editable by anyone.

Facebook says that the process takes up to 24 hours but it's been 3 days and still shows me this

```
"(#100) Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description params."
```

So I tried another angle, their `/{page-id}/photos` endpoint

```
{
  "url": "img-url"
}
```

And this works great, I can publish a photo, and then I tried (with and without the "value" parameter inside call_to_action)

```
{  
  "call_to_action": {
    "type": "MESSAGE_PAGE",
    "value": {
      "link": "link-page"
    }
  },
  "url": "img-url"
}
```

But I get the next error

```
"(#10) Application does not have permission for this action"
```

Comment: The documentation for uploading photos says nothing about a `call_to_action` parameter, so I see no reason to assume that it was possible to specify one when uploading photos.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, It was a long shot

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this by using manually configured Firebase Dynamic Links as stated on their docs.

Posting this to their `/{page-id}/feed` endpoint

```
{
  "call_to_action": {
    "type": "MESSAGE_PAGE",
    "value": {
      "link":"yourdomain.com/?link=https://m.me/{page-id}&st=title&sd=description&si=img-url"
    }
  },
  "link":"yourdomain.com/?link=https://m.me/{page-id}&st=title&sd=description&si=img-url"
  "message": "message"
}
```

[Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews)